# az command to view Azure App Service Log Stream?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-log-analytics, azure-appservice, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Is there a command to view Azure App Service Log Stream entries from the command line? I would like to tail the logs on my local console.

[image: Azure Portal menu with log stream selected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can stream the Web App logs using:

```
az webapp log tail [--ids]
                   [--name]
                   [--provider]
                   [--resource-group]
                   [--slot]
                   [--subscription]
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Ah, the `webapp` command was throwing me off. I thought that was for static web apps, not app service... unfortunate naming convention. Thanks!